# Generalized spectral theorem for QM of damped systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics

I used to think that the mathematical formalization of Quantum Mechanics through Borel functional calculus for unbounded self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces and the one given in terms of **Rigged Hilbert spaces** (or **Gelfand triples**) were substantially equivalent.

The two formulations always appeared equivalent to me since they lead to the same spectral theorem for an unbounded self-adjoint operator $A$ on $\mathcal{H}$, written as $A=\int_{\sigma(A)}\lambda\, d P^A(\lambda)$ in the former case and as $ A=\int_{\sigma(A)}\lambda\, |\lambda\rangle\langle \lambda |$, where now the Dirac bra-ket notation makes sense in terms of distributions, in the latter.

However, from the papers [1] and [2] it appears that the Hilbert space formalism is not useful in treating damped systems, i.e. systems for which the energy is not conserved.

> In [2] they quantize a simple damped motion in one dimension, $\dot{x}=-\gamma x$, $\gamma>0$, obtaining a quantum Hamiltonian operator on $\mathcal{H}:=L^2(\mathbb{R})$ of the form $$H=-\frac{\gamma}{2}(XP+PX)=i\gamma\left(x\frac{d}{dx}+\frac12\right).$$
> Through a canonical transformation it can be shown that this is equivalent to the **inverted harmonic oscillator** with Hamiltonian $\frac12 (P^2-\gamma X^2)$. Choosing $\mathrm{dom}(H):=\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ one easily sees that $H$ is essentially self-adjoint (it is not done in the paper -- they do not even mention a domain for $H$ at all -- but it is not too difficult to calculate the *deficiency indices*) and the unique self-adjoint extension is determined by Stone's theorem applied to the family of unitary operators $U(t):=e^{\gamma t/2}e^{\gamma t x\partial_x}(=e^{-itH}$ on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}))$. The paper just calls $H$ such unique self-adjoint extension.

> It can also be shown that $\sigma(H)=\mathbb{R}$, but there is also a family of generalized eigenfunctions $\{f_n^\pm\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}\subset\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ with imaginary generalized eigenvalues $\pm E_n:=\pm i\gamma\left( n+\frac12\right)$.

> Moreover, they identify two Rigged Hilbert spaces $\Phi_\pm\subset L^2(\mathbb{R})\subset \Phi'_\pm$ where $\Phi_-:=\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $\Phi_-:=\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ ($\mathcal{F}$ being the unitary Fourier transform) such that
> $$ H=\sum_n \bar{E_n}|f_n^-\rangle\langle f_n^+|\quad \text{on } \Phi_-,$$
> $$ H=\sum_n {E_n}|f_n^+\rangle\langle f_n^-|\quad \text{on } \Phi_+,$$
> and by restricting $U(t)$ for example to the space $\Phi_-$ we get a semigroup $U_-(t):\Phi_-\to\Phi_-$, $t\geq 0$ so that for $\psi_-\in\Phi_-$
> $$ U_-(t)\psi_- =\sum_n e^{-\gamma (n+1/2)t}|f_n^-\rangle\langle f_n^+|\psi_-\rangle\in\Phi_-$$
> and this reflects the irreversible behaviour of the classical system $\dot{x}=-\gamma x$, namely $x(t)=e^{-\gamma t} x(0)$.

The authors claim that the usual mathematical formulation of QM in terms of PVMs cannot deal with this situation and we have to treat complex generalized eigenvalues somehow separately within the context of **Rigged Hilbert spaces**. In my opinion this happens because the spectral theorem that we have *only sees the generalized eigenfunctions with real generalized eigenvalue* (since they are the only ones that -- in some sense -- are *unitarily contributing* to the decomposition of $\mathcal{H}$).

Is my interpretation correct?

I wonder if there exists some general result providing a spectral decomposition in generalized eigenfunctions also for **complex generalized eigenspaces** within the context of the Borel functional calculus/PVMs formulation, possibly to be applied only to a certain subspace (like $\Phi_\pm$ in the example).

In any case it still puzzles me why it is often said that the two formulations are equivalent, since the the traditional PVM one cannot properly handle such cases.

ADDENDUM: It appears to me that the authors do not really clarify the role of the domain of $H$. It is possible that choosing $\Phi_-$ as a domain for $H$, $H|_{\Phi_-}$ is then nothing more than a **normal** unbounded operator and that the set $\{E_n\}$ of imaginary eigenvalues constitutes the spectrum of $H|_{\Phi_-}$ (although I cannot prove any of this). In that case the spectral theorem for normal operators would solve the issue and there would be no need to talk about Rigged Hilbert spaces. But this is all just conjectural.

---

[1]: Castagnino, M., Diener, R., Lara, L. et al. "Rigged Hilbert spaces and time asymmetry: The case of the upside-down simple harmonic oscillator." Int J Theor Phys 36, 2349–2369 (1997). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02768929

[2]: Chruściński, Dariusz. "Quantum mechanics of damped systems." Journal of Mathematical Physics 44.9 (2003): 3718-3733. https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0301024v3

Comment: Ciao Rubens! In my view this construction has not much to do with the spectral decomposition which is a generalization of the standard decomposition with respect to an orthonormal basis. Hence the structure is $\sum_k |u_k><u_k|x>$. In the construction you point out there are *two* families of vectors used simultaneously instead: $\sum_k |u_k><z_k|x>$. This has nothing to do with the ideas of spectral theory because it is not an *orthogonal* decomposition along *eigenvectors*

Comment: The question is very good and deserves a long technical answer. I will for now tell you that von Neumann's spectral theorem for a self-adjoint operator has two restrictions: the spectrum of the operator is real and if it is not pure point ("discrete"), then the spectral measure cannot be realized as a true projector in the Hilbert space. Going to RHS is a benefit from one pointof view: if the subspace is restricted enough, the spectrum of the "shifted-to-distribution space" operator could have discrete complex spectral values. That would not be "a tight rigging".

Comment: I suggest you to read de la Madrid's PhD thesis, especially the chapter on Gamow vectors.

Comment: For the same reason it is not an expansion in the sense of Rigged Hilbert spaces, where again only one family of eigenfunctions is used in the expansion. Here instead, this mixed use permits the appearance of complex "eigenvalues" in spite of the fact that the operator is symmetric. I am not arguing that the presented result do not have physical interest. I am just observing that the contruction is radically different of the standard spectral expansions.

Comment: The issue in the addendum is ineffective. If the operator were normal the spectral decomposition would be in terms of **orthogonal** projectors in any case. Here the projectors taking place in the expansions are not orthogonal, since they are $|f_n^\pm><f_n^\mp|$.